# post photo to facebook wall using windows phone app

Tags: facebook, windows-phone

I am trying to post a photo to facebook wall, for which I am using Facebook c# sdk. I have used the following code :

```
 var fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
 {
    { "message", "Olav is testing Facebook C# SDK" },
    { "picture", "http://download.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=facebooksdk&DownloadId=170794&Build=17672" },
    { "name", "Facebook C# SDK" },
    { "caption", "http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/" },
    { "description", "The Facebook C# SDK helps .Net developers build web, desktop, Silverlight, and Windows Phone 7 applications that integrate with Facebook." },
    { "privacy", new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "value",  "SELF" }
        }
    }
};

        fb.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);
```

It is working fine for the given picture url. But what if i want the picture to be the one created by the user using the phone app. If I give any value to picture field other than a url, then it gives an error. Can someone please tell how to do this, or is there any other method to post an image from app to facebook wall?

Answer (score 0):

Your image should be uploaded to the server beforehand.

So if you want user to post an image to Facebook page you need to upload image to your server and get and URL for it.

Then you can use this URL to post on Facebook page.